# How exactly does Bidirectional (Stepwise) elimination works?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, stepwise-regression

I read about Forward selection and Backward elimination algorithms while learning to build machine learning models. I think I'm not quite clear on next approach, which was bidirectional elimination(which is also known as stepwise regression I assume)

I understood following concepts regarding both of them : 
(1) **Forward selection** : It builds model by selecting the variables, one by one, which have lowest p-value less than significance level. (In other words, select a variable, which best improves the model). 

(2) **Backward elimination** : It starts with all variables, and then removes one variable at a time, which has highest p-value greater than significance level. In other words, remove variable, that is least required in the model.

Now concept of bidirectional elimination, which uses both of above methods is not fitting well into my mind. It says:

1. select the significance level to enter and stay a variable in model.
2. Followed by this, it performs steps of forward selection and then backward elimination.

While the article does not contain any worked example. I watched a video on youtube about this, but it just followed the steps of forward selection and nothing about backward elimination. It would be awesome if someone could explain how exactly stepwise regression works or provide some useful resources to learn this concepts well.

Comment: OLS is very fast, such that all possible combinations of input variables - including with and without an offset - that have a defined number of coefficients can be fitted and a result list created. The list would contain which input combination was used and the related fit statistics such as RMSE or R-squared. This allows you to fit all combinations with, say, two or three coefficients and then rank the fitting results for analysis. Note that if the number of combinations is large, the list size can be huge - in such cases only keep a list of the top few hundred fits. This is sometimes useful.

Comment: @James You describe *all subsets selection.*  Although it's useful to know about it, bear in mind (1) it is effective for at most 30-40 independent variables (depending on computing resources) and (2) it does not provide much insight into the issues raised in this question.

Comment: Just wanted to point out for future readers that all subsets selection can be efficiently solved for p in the 1000s using modern optimization tools: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03133